# Normal unit vector in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, surfaces, cylindrical-coordinates

Suppose I have a surface in cylindrical coordinates given by $z=f(r,\theta)$. How can I proceed to find the normal unit vector of this surface?

My initial guess was to evaluate it's gradient, which will give me the vector (not normalized):

$$\underline{n}=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r},\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta},-1\right)$$
And then divide its component by the length $\sqrt{n_r^2+n_z^2}$ to obtain the normal unit vector.
However, I've found on the internet that the normal vector of a surface is given by $\frac{\partial \underline{F}}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial \underline{F}}{\partial\theta}$, where $\underline{F}$ is the regular parametrization of the surface. Taking for the present example $\underline{F}=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,f(r,\theta))$:

$$\underline{n} = \frac{\partial \underline{F}}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial \underline{F}}{\partial\theta} = \left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} - r\cos\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} , -r\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} - \cos\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta},r \right) $$

Which does not look to be the same. Can anyone help me on how can I evaluate this quantity? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the surface in $(x,y,z)$-space or in $(r,\theta,z)$-space?

Comment: The problem is posed in the $(r,\theta,z)$-space since the surface is given by $z=f(r,\theta)$

Comment: Normally, when you say cylindrical coordinates you are working in $(x,y,z)$-space, so it’s not clear to me.

Comment: Hmm... I think I've confused it. I'm working with a surface on the $(x,y,z)$-space, but I'm describing it by its cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$. My problem is how can I evaluate its normal unit vector.

Comment: The correct way is to write parametric equations, as you did in the second solution, and compute the fundamental cross product. This works with any parametric representation.

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin. The problem follows that I need to integrate the $z$ component of this normal as $\int{\int_D{(\underline{e}_z\cdot\underline{n})rdrd\theta}}$. Is it going to be right to adopt the second representation? I was concerned about this particular expression in particular

Comment: You probably should state the precise problem to be sure. Are we doing a surface integral over this surface? Also, remember that they expect you to write the *unit* normal, and you haven't done that. But if you're doing a surface integral, the length of your $\underline n$ is the "fudge factor" and it cancels out.

Comment: I'll take a try and if I cant get the answer then I'll state the whole problem. It's an integral of a quantity (that depends on the unit normal) over the surface. Moreover, how do I evaluate the unit normal in the second representation? Should I divide it by the norm with all three components? Thanks!